# animation from top to bottom swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

Is there a way to make an animation in which you can present the view from top to bottom. Like if the user swipes down on a view it shows a new controller by coming top to bottom. Right now I have it as a swipe gesture as well. I've been trying to add it in the prepare method by setting an if statement for the specific identifier. I appreciate any help to my answer. Thank you